# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Don't use localized validation messages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 and DataAnnotations validations and for some reason the javascript validations show localized messages. I would like to use the default english validation messages, since the whole application is in english.

I don't remember configuring any localization, how does the validation mechanism detect the language?

How should I alter my application to use english messages?

I've searched the internet but others seem to have the exact opposite problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set culture in `global.asax`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I've set culture in <globalization> in my Web.config to 'en-us' and it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `web.config` is another approach that does not require explicit code:

```xml
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>
  ...
<system.web>
```

I would only set the culture in `global.asax` when there is a real requirement for that e.g. a user dependent culture:

```
User persistedUser = UserService.GetByDomainUserName( user.Name );
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = persistedUser.Culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = persistedUser.UICulture;
```

This code would then be placed in the `PostAuthenticateRequest` event.

Answer (score 0):

I get the trouble,looks www.fentime.com,click the login,

the setting is zh-CN,but because the server havn't install the zh-cn language package,so the prompt words is english.I think it's a bug with MVC.